# pandas dataframe, if condition match and index next to each other: add value and delete the row used

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, drop

I want to drop queried dataframe - rows and replace it with new data when the index are next to each other.

basically adding value i-1 to i.

is this possible to be done ?

please see the example data below:
if i have a data frame as above: i want to amend the dataframe as below

```
import pandas as pd 

training_data = pd.DataFrame()

training_data['a'] = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7]
training_data['b'] = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7]

training_data['c'] = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,6,7]
training_data['condition'] = [True,True,False,False,True,True,False,False,True,False,False,False,True]


True_data = training_data[training_data['condition'] == True]


True_data:

index    a    b    c    condition   

0       1     1    1      True      

1       1     1    1      True 

4       2     2    2      True

5       3     3    3      True

8       4     4    4      True 

12      7     7    7      True 


desired output:

index    a    b    c    condition   


new     2     2    2      True 

new     5     5    5      True 

8       4     4    4      True

12      7     7    7      True
```

All added values have index next to each other however,8, 12 does not thus will not be added.

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: hey Bisal, can you add your data as text and any attempts you've made to solve this problem on your own? please read [mcve]

Comment: @Manakin will do, edit otw. Thanks

Comment: @Manakin updated. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you count both rows at 8 and 9 to sum to 8?

Comment: @ScottBoston, sorry scott that's meant to be counted my bad. : i will edit it accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
grp = (~training_data['condition']).cumsum()
training_data.query('condition')\
             .groupby(grp)\
             .agg({'a':'sum','b':'sum','c':'sum','condition':'first'})
```

Output:

```
           a  b  c  condition
condition                    
0          2  2  2       True
2          5  5  5       True
4          8  8  8       True
6          7  7  7       True
```

Updated with new data:

```
training_data['grp'] =  (~training_data['condition']).cumsum()

training_data.query('condition').groupby('grp').agg({'a':'sum','b':'sum','c':'sum','condition':'first'})
```

Output:

```
     a  b  c  condition
grp                    
0    2  2  2       True
2    5  5  5       True
4    4  4  4       True
7    7  7  7       True
```

Comment: i am getting list with column as condition :series(13,)

Comment: Check the dtype of training_data['condition'] column is it a boolean and not a string?

Comment: it does say dtype: bool when checked

Comment: Sorry yes, its a bool